# MUI4 with React18 createRoot method

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-dom

I'm currently on a project that still uses mui4 and react16. I just upgraded to react18 but still using the reactDOM.render method. Has anyone used mui4 with react18 createRoot method? any issues with it?

Comment: You said you upgraded, have you tried it yet?

Comment: I tried, but it causes some of the spacing to render differently. Not sure what is the problem

Comment: You may want to add that to your question, along with some of the code that is rendering differently, that way we can see what is going on, and we can help with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)